# What does array[1..-2] mean?

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

I've come across a code snippet where index access is defined with a range ending with a minus value.

```
array[1..-2]
```

What's the purpose of this?

Comment: This is very clearly covered in the Array documentation section for [Accessing Elements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ruby (as well as Python, Perl, and a few other languages), a negative array index is interpreted relative to the end of the array. `array[-1]` is the last element of the array; `array[-2]` is the next to last.

So this is a slice of the array omitting the first and last elements.

Comment: Perl also uses negative indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are Zero Indexed meaning they start at 0 instead of 1. For example, let's suppose we created an array

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

The first array element, which is indexed at 0 and is indicated by numbers[0] would return 1. Here are the indices

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Meaning this numbers array is indexed from 0 to 9 and not 1 to 10.

There are two methods for finding the last value of an array.

```
numbers[8]
```

or if you didn't know the number of values in an array you could do

```
numbers[-1]
```

This would return the number 9.

What you mentioned is the range notation, indicated by a starting value, two consecutive dots and an ending value.

In your example

```
array[1..-2]
```

Means it would return all values of the array starting with the 2nd element and ending with the 2nd to last element. If we called it on my numbers array

```
numbers[1..-2]
```

It would return

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

In other words all values inclusive starting at the second value(2) and ending at the second to last value (9). On the other hand

```
numbers[1...-2]
```

with 3 dots indicate the range is exclusive and contains all values starting at the second value BENEATH the second to last value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

That is taking all the elements from the second element to the second-to-last element. In other words, it truncates the first and last element. See [this link](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/996814716/use-negative-array-indices) for more information on negative array indices.